# Unable to get the classname and method with @Before Aspect

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have implemented AOP for logging purpose.

LoggingAspect

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
  private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

  @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
  public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
    System.out.println("classname : " + joinPoint.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "," + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("******");
  }
}
```

and the following configuration in app-ctx.xml

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.pms" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="loggingAspect"
        class="com.pms.advice.LoggingAspect" />
</beans>
```

but it output for all classes I get

```
logBefore() is running!
classname : org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint,getConnection
******
```

please advice

Answer (score 0):

I will never understand why so many developers call methods on `JoinPoint` in order to extract specific information they get for free when just logging the joinpoint instance itself. There is everything: the joinpoint type, the method signature with class name and return type. This is what you need if you really want to know what is going on in your aspects. Hiding information by just logging a part of it makes debugging so much more difficult. Plus, calling a lot of methods does not make the logging aspect faster. And then they complain AOP is "slow". ;-)

Anyway, for what it is worth, you want to use `joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()` here. What you are logging instead are the joinpoint class and the name of the intercepted method.

Attention, `joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType()` would give you the dynamic proxy's type which is probably not what you want.

**Update:** If you use `((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).get*()` you have access to a couple more getters:

```
Method getMethod()
Class getReturnType()
Class[] getParameterTypes()
Class[] getExceptionTypes()
String[] getParameterNames()
String toString()
int getModifiers()
String getName()
String toShortString()
String toLongString()
Class getDeclaringType()
String getDeclaringTypeName()
```

And, interesting enough, in this case `((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getDeclaringType()` gives you the real class and not the proxy class.

Comment: It is still not working  I tried ((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getDeclaringTypeName()   i,e,   System.out.println("******Method Name:" + ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getDeclaringTypeName());  but i still get output ******Method Name:javax.sql.DataSource  instead of every method.  please advise

Comment: Of course, your question was why the wrong class name was printed. I showed you how to print the right class name. So what's the problem? If you want the method name, just print it like you already know how to do - see your own sample code. Now if there is nothing else I would appreciate you to accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: the problem is I am getting same output , where as i should get respective class and method name . Looks like I am missing or doing something wrong. I have specified my code above

Comment: A comment is not suitable for posting code. Please edit your question, adding the new code on the bottom. And BTW, I agree that you must be doing something wrong. Without insight into your code I cannot say what, though. I tested my code, it works. The easiest way to reproduce your problem would be to post a full sample project on GitHub for me to clone and run.

Comment: *joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()* works for me and gives implemented class name.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to party but it might help someone.

I believe that @Aaruhi want its implemented classes to be logged. If answer is yes, then this will help:

```
@Before("execution(* <your_pakage_name>..*.*(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
   System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
   System.out.println("classname : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "," + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
   System.out.println("******");
}
```

This will print logs for all private, public and internal methods. Please update `<your_pakage_name>`, this enables logging for all classes that fall under given `<your_pakage_name>`.

`joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()`
 - This will print your implementing class name.

**NOTE** - Update pointcut expression to `execution(public * <your_pakage_name>..*.*(..))` to enable logging for public methods only.